How do I customise Linux sensors3 outputs?
I'm currently trying to set up the output of sensors/lmsensors to be a bit more sensible. I'm running Ubuntu 24.04. I'm trying to do 2 things - neaten up/rename various devices and put them in a more logical order - according to the Arch Linux docs, I can 'simply' put a configuration file in /etc/sensors.d and it'll override the appropriate values
As an experiment, I tried 'just' overriding my 10G card - I'd ideally want the 6 SCSI drives in order (and once I figure out which is which, name them by bay), and have them below everything else, as well as renaming things a bit more logically.
I guess there's the matter of "what's wrong with my config file" and "can I get the desired results from sensors"?
I've tried editing my /etc/sensors3.conf, as well as setting up a seperate file in the sensors.d folder. I've also tried explicitly setting the config file while running it.
geek@zimanas1:/etc/sensors.d$ cat zimacube
chip "10G-pci-0e00"

    label temp1_input "NIC Temperature"
    label temp2_input "MAC Temperature"

The full output is as below - the changes I made weren't picked up
geek@zimanas1:/etc$ sudo sensors
drivetemp-scsi-4-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:        +39.0°C  (low  =  +1.0°C, high = +61.0°C)
                       (crit low =  +2.0°C, crit = +60.0°C)
                       (lowest = +26.0°C, highest = +45.0°C)

drivetemp-scsi-2-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:        +45.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high = +60.0°C)
                       (crit low = -40.0°C, crit = +70.0°C)
                       (lowest = +28.0°C, highest = +49.0°C)

drivetemp-scsi-0-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:        +38.0°C  (low  = +10.0°C, high = +40.0°C)
                       (crit low =  +5.0°C, crit = +60.0°C)
                       (lowest = +27.0°C, highest = +43.0°C)

nvme-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +35.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +76.8°C)
                       (crit = +78.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C

drivetemp-scsi-5-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:        +43.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high = +60.0°C)
                       (crit low = -40.0°C, crit = +70.0°C)
                       (lowest = +27.0°C, highest = +48.0°C)

drivetemp-scsi-3-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:        +45.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high = +60.0°C)
                       (crit low = -41.0°C, crit = +85.0°C)
                       (lowest = +27.0°C, highest = +50.0°C)

drivetemp-scsi-1-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:        +42.0°C  (low  = +10.0°C, high = +40.0°C)
                       (crit low =  +5.0°C, crit = +60.0°C)
                       (lowest = +27.0°C, highest = +46.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:        +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:        +46.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

10G-pci-0e00
Adapter: PCI adapter
PHY Temperature:  +58.0°C
MAC Temperature:  +58.0°C

Thr raw output of sensors - via sensors -u would be useful in cross checking/building out the config file
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:
  temp1_input: 46.000
  temp1_max: 105.000
  temp1_crit: 105.000
  temp1_crit_alarm: 0.000
Core 0:
  temp2_input: 46.000
  temp2_max: 105.000
  temp2_crit: 105.000
  temp2_crit_alarm: 0.000
Core 1:
  temp3_input: 45.000
  temp3_max: 105.000
  temp3_crit: 105.000
  temp3_crit_alarm: 0.000
Core 2:
  temp4_input: 45.000
  temp4_max: 105.000
  temp4_crit: 105.000
  temp4_crit_alarm: 0.000
Core 3:
  temp5_input: 45.000
  temp5_max: 105.000
  temp5_crit: 105.000


drivetemp-scsi-0-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:
  temp1_input: 38.000
  temp1_max: 40.000
  temp1_min: 10.000
  temp1_crit: 60.000
  temp1_lcrit: 5.000
  temp1_lowest: 27.000
  temp1_highest: 43.000

drivetemp-scsi-1-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:
  temp1_input: 41.000
  temp1_max: 40.000
  temp1_min: 10.000
  temp1_crit: 60.000
  temp1_lcrit: 5.000
  temp1_lowest: 27.000
  temp1_highest: 46.000

drivetemp-scsi-2-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:
  temp1_input: 44.000
  temp1_max: 60.000
  temp1_min: 0.000
  temp1_crit: 70.000
  temp1_lcrit: -40.000
  temp1_lowest: 28.000
  temp1_highest: 49.000


drivetemp-scsi-3-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:
  temp1_input: 44.000
  temp1_max: 60.000
  temp1_min: 0.000
  temp1_crit: 85.000
  temp1_lcrit: -41.000
  temp1_lowest: 27.000
  temp1_highest: 50.000

drivetemp-scsi-4-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:
  temp1_input: 39.000
  temp1_max: 61.000
  temp1_min: 1.000
  temp1_crit: 60.000
  temp1_lcrit: 2.000
  temp1_lowest: 26.000
  temp1_highest: 45.000

drivetemp-scsi-5-0
Adapter: SCSI adapter
temp1:
  temp1_input: 43.000
  temp1_max: 60.000
  temp1_min: 0.000
  temp1_crit: 70.000
  temp1_lcrit: -40.000
  temp1_lowest: 27.000
  temp1_highest: 48.000

nvme-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:
  temp1_input: 35.850
  temp1_max: 76.850
  temp1_min: -0.150
  temp1_crit: 78.850
  temp1_alarm: 0.000

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:
  temp1_input: 27.800
  temp5_crit_alarm: 0.000

10G-pci-0e00
Adapter: PCI adapter
PHY Temperature:
  temp1_input: 57.000
MAC Temperature:
  temp2_input: 57.000


Apparently there's other issues with HDD related adjustment of labels in sensors - I may need to look at other approaches to get my intended end goal.
For relabelling the other sensors though, this worked - I dropped the '_input', which wasn't obvious to me from the docs, This changes PHY temperature to NIC Temperature and hides the second reading.
chip "10G-pci-0e00"

    label temp1 "NIC Temperature"
    #label temp2 "MAC Temperature"
    ignore "temp2"

Now, that's probably not good enough for what I need, so I did some ugly bash scripting. Sensors3 would do json output - and I can use jq to organise these to something a bit more usable, and sorted.
I just ended up sorting the json output, and stripping everything I didn't need with gratuitious use of grep, cut and tr
sensors -j | jq -S -r | tr -d \{  | tr -d \} | tr -d \, | tr -d \" | grep -v -E "alarm|crit|max|min|highest|lowest" | grep -E 'drivetemp-scsi|pci' -A4 | grep -v  -E "Adapter|temp1:|Composite:"| grep -v "\-\-" | grep "\S"

This gave me the following output
  10G-pci-0e00:
    NIC Temperature:
      temp1_input: 51.000
  drivetemp-scsi-0-0:
      temp1_input: 38.000
  drivetemp-scsi-1-0:
      temp1_input: 41.000
  drivetemp-scsi-2-0:
      temp1_input: 45.000
  drivetemp-scsi-3-0:
      temp1_input: 45.000
  drivetemp-scsi-4-0:
      temp1_input: 40.000
  drivetemp-scsi-5-0:
      temp1_input: 43.000
  nvme-pci-0500:
      temp1_input: 35.850

Which is very close to what I need. I can grab the values I need (maybe a bit more elegantly) for use elsewhere.
